# Verify account link doesn't work and doesn't allow to login for every new org or every new user

Tags: user, setup, org, outlook, trial

Whenever I create a new Devhub trial org, or any kind of trial org, or even Developer Edition org, and follow Verify Account link, it redirects me to login page and doesn't allow to set my password or setup a security question.

Every time I have to open another Salesforce Support case to fix this problem and reset a password for every new org.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I have found solution today on a call with Salesforce Support. I use MS Outlook as email app. It has a 'Safety link' feature which opens internally a link before you actually click it. Salesforce 'Verify Account' link is meant to be one-time, so if MS Outlook opens the link before you open it, when you open it in a browser it is considered as second time and doesn't allow you to login and setup your password and security questions.

So the solution is either use a different email app, or copy the Verify Account link and open it into an anonymous browser window to prevent any conflicts with other Salesforce user logins. This solution works as a charm.

However, if you have already clicked the link, there is no other way to restore access except contacting Salesforce support.